# BootChamp equivalent to go from Windows to Mac

Tags: windows, bootcamp, dual-boot

I use BootChamp to restart into Windows directly from OS X. I was wondering if there is an equivalent piece of software to restart from Windows into Mac. This will be especially useful when using remote access.

Comment: How do you use Bootcamp to restart into Windows?

Answer (score 1):

BootChamp only sets the next boot, so to get from Windows to OS X **just reboot normally**!
It will boot into OS X by itself, since the default boot disk is still OS X.

Comment: If the default boot is Windows though ... ?